# How to rephrase the term "physical sciences"?

Tags: differences

A distinction is often made in the natural sciences between the *life sciences* and the *physical sciences*. Semantically, I believe this is a false distinction. Since all life depends on a physical dimension, *life sciences* would be a subset of the *physical sciences*. However, this defeats the point of the distinction, i.e. to distinguish between science where the system under study is necessarily living (biology), and science where there is no special treatment of living systems (physics and chemistry).

Is there an alternative way to make this distinction?

Comment: I deny your major. By this line of reasoning, *everything* except mathematics and metaphysics is a "subset of the physical sciences" -- history, sociology, psychology, economics, art history, even English Language & Usage.

Comment: So would you say that the *physical sciences* refers to the study of everything excluding those covered by other disciplines?

Comment: Well, I'm probably one of the last people on this site you should ask: what I know about the "hard" sciences was pretty well fixed 50 years ago. But I was always impressed with the notion of "emergence phenomena": life "emerging" from non-life, social life "emerging" from animal life, &c. The "physical sciences" for me are those which deal **only** with what is physical: matter and energy.

Comment: So Biology and Chemistry should be lumped under Physics?

Comment: [There is only mathematics; that is all that exists](http://discovermagazine.com/2008/jul/16-is-the-universe-actually-made-of-math).

Comment: There are many ways to cut this cake. What lines in the sand do you require?

Comment: All science is either physics or stamp collecting

Comment: Huh, OP? This is ELU! The taxonomical, philosophical and dialectical issues raised are in no way in the domain of Language and Literature, not English. I vote to close as  too localized.

Comment: I'm looking for an alternative to the term *physical sciences*. There are issues to consider from other domains but at the heart of this is semantics, which I believe falls under the remit of ELU.

Comment: @StoneyB your implication that the life sciences and social sciences differ from the physical sciences due to consideration of emergence in the former two, is appealing.

Comment: The life sciences **used to be** considered part of the physical sciences. From Google books 1839: "But of the physical sciences the most beautiful and alluring is botany."

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps the distinction could be *organic* and *non-organic*. This would allow the inclusion of organic chemistry on the *bio* side, while leaving everything else as *non*.

Comment: @tchrist understood, but it is a core part of the biologically focused sciences

Comment: But "organic sciences" is *less* satisfactory and accurate a term than "life sciences"; while your terms *may* have a clearer separation and less overlap (which is debatable), I don't see that it's an improvement overall.

Answer (score 1):

There's always 'life sciences' and 'the non-life sciences'.  If context might allow the social sciences to be included in the non-life sciences, then you could say 'the other hard sciences.'  Of course, some people think that biology and its friends are not hard sciences, and others think the concept of a 'hard' vs. a soft science in the first place is chauvinistic and even derogatory.

Anyway, as others have mentioned, I think this is a moot point.  Life sciences is a subset of physical sciences only under a construal of physical sciences that people that correctly use the phrase "physical sciences" don't intend to make.

It's safest to stick with 'physical sciences' in either event.